# how to convert JSon array to Arraylist with the help of pojoclass?

Tags: java, android, json, listadapter

I am unable to get any result from my code.please suggest the solution for my problem, here is my code and thanks in Advance

CODE: Activity.main

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ArrayList<detail> country =  new ArrayList<detail>();

 class detail{
    public String toponymName;
    public String countrycode;
    public int population;
    public String wikipedia;
    }

   Adapter ad = null;
   static ArrayList<string> resultrow;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?        north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");

    ListView mylistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    ad = new Adapter();
    mylistview.setAdapter(ad);

    }
    public static String GET(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
         inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
         if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());}
         return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        Log.e("Line",line);
         result += line;
    }
     inputStream.close();
    return result;
    }

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return GET(urls[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String strJson = result;

        try {
           JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
           JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("geonames");
           for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
               JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               detail resultrow = new detail();
               resultrow.toponymName =jsonObject.getString("toponymName");
               resultrow.countrycode =jsonObject.getString("countrycode");
               resultrow.wikipedia =jsonObject.getString("wikipedia");
               resultrow.population =jsonObject.getInt("population");
               country.add(resultrow);
       }

        }
           catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
    } 

    }
    class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<detail>{
    Adapter(){
                  super(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,country);
    }
    public View getview(int position,View convertview,ViewGroup parent){
        viewHolder holder;

    if(convertview==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
        convertview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
        holder = new viewHolder(convertview);
        convertview.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder=(viewHolder)convertview.getTag();
    }
    holder.populateFrom(country.get(position));
    return convertview;
    }
    }
    class viewHolder{
    public TextView toponymName=null;
    public TextView countrycode=null;
    public TextView wikipedia=null;
    public TextView population=null;

    viewHolder(View row){
        toponymName =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.toponymName);
        countrycode =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.countrycode);  
        wikipedia =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.wikipedia);  
        population =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.population);    
        }

      //not able to populate this block 
       void populateFrom(detail r){
        toponymName.setText(r.toponymName);
        countrycode.setText(r.countrycode);
        wikipedia.setText(r.wikipedia);
        population.setText(r.population);
    }
    } 
    }
```

sometimes also get this error :

> {"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has
>   been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use
>   the demo account for your application.","value":18}}

please tell me what is this error

Comment: This seems to be warning from server saying : the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application....rather depending on demo account create your own specific account

Comment: how to remove this error

Comment: At the end of the url I see username="demo" is that account specific to you? Anyways that account must be using free web services...but they might have limitation on given day how many times you can hit that web service with particular account...also can various library for json parsing do a google search

Comment: thanks you very much and can you suggest the solution that why i am not getting the result in arraylist

Comment: Since you are parsing manually and especially looking for geoname  array with line JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("geonames"); and your json object has only status as Json object within which message and value as json string so your jsonArray is empty :) Check this : http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Comment: created an account on geonames but still cannot get the end result, getting json array data though

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know that why you are using this pojo concept here.

Anyway , I can only suggest you do add some getter/setter in side the class. like

```
class detail{
    public String toponymName;
    public String countrycode;
    public int population;
    public String wikipedia;
    public String getToponymName() {
        return toponymName;
    }
    public void setToponymName(String toponymName) {
        this.toponymName = toponymName;
    }
    public String getCountrycode() {
        return countrycode;
    }
    public void setCountrycode(String countrycode) {
        this.countrycode = countrycode;
    }
    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }
    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }
    public String getWikipedia() {
        return wikipedia;
    }
    public void setWikipedia(String wikipedia) {
        this.wikipedia = wikipedia;
    }


    }
```

It will help you to set and get particular data from JSON String.

Something like:

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           detail resultrow = new detail();
           resultrow.setToponymName(jsonObject.getString("toponymName");
          ..........
          .......
           country.add(resultrow);
```

When you want to set it:: Just do

```
toponymName.setText(r.getToponymName());
..................................
..................................
```

Comment: still i am not getting any result , i am able to get data from json but not able to put that data in listview so please suggest the solution

Comment: You still not put any data in your Adapter, its blank. You should have to put this ArrayList in your adapter so it can use in ListView.

Comment: i am putting the data in arraylist<country > and then using it from adapter but not getting any result

Comment: Look here: ListView mylistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    ad = new Adapter();
    mylistview.setAdapter(ad); ...your adapter is still null.

Comment: i tried this and i am getting a gibberish data but not actual data.                     ad = new Adapter(this, country);
               ListView mylistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
                mylistview.setAdapter(ad);

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check this library out [Ion Library](https://github.com/koush/ion).
It will help you to async fetch JSON & easily convert it into `ArrayList` of POJO.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<PojoClass> pojoClassList;

pojoClassList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString,TypeFactory.collectionType(List.class, Employe.class));
```

Suggest u read about Gson or Jakson libs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your view holder pattern to implementation as shown below. And also change the constructor of Adapter to either one implementation as shown below.

```
class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<detail>{
  //below variables are optional
  List<detail> actList;
  Context context;

  Adapter(Context context, Context context, int resource, List<detail> actList){
   super(context,resource,actList);
   //below variables are optional
   this.context  = context;
   this.actList = actList;
  }

  ---OR----

  Adapter(Context context, Context context, int resource){
   super(context,resource);
   //below variables are optional
   this.context  = context;
  }

  public View getview(int position,View convertview,ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder holder;
    final detail r = actList.get(position);

    if(convertview==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
        convertview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.toponymName =(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.toponymName);
        holder.countrycode =(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.countrycode);  
        holder.wikipedia =(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.wikipedia);  
        holder.population =(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.population);

        convertview.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertview.getTag();
    }

    if(r!= null) {
     holder.toponymName.setText(r.toponymName);
     holder.countrycode.setText(r.countrycode);
     holder.wikipedia.setText(r.wikipedia);
     holder.population.setText(r.population);
    }

    return convertview;
 }
}

static class ViewHolder{

  TextView toponymName;
  TextView countrycode;
  TextView wikipedia;
  TextView population;

}
```

And while initializing the adapter do as follows depending on constructor utilized.

```
ad = new Adapter(this, R.layout.row, actlist)
OR
ad = new Adapter(this, R.layout.row)
```

**Updates Based** on the new comment
**Firstly mistakes**
 
1)One thing I observed what you are doing is starting asynctask and **setting the adapter to list without gurantee of data is fetched or not in the onCreate method so your list might be empty**...you can do it that way but then you need to **update the list in adapter and notify adapter of changed dataset**
2)Secondly I **observed many list objects in your code which is bit confusing** .Also you have used lot of static things...reason I don't know; but I feel it is redundant. The methods like `GET(String url)` *[---which should be named as get(String url)]* and `convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)` **could be created in HttpAsyncTask bcoz it is used by that thread only**.
3)Also you are not using anything to show that data is loading from server

So **few more changes** that I would add on the adapter change as explained previously.
1)Make instance variable for ListView as follows and change in onCreate method also create method to setAdapter

```
Adapter ad = null;
ListView listView;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView mylistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);

    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?           north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");
}

public void setListAdapter(){
  if(ad == null){
    ad = new Adapter(this, R.layout.row)
    mylistview.setAdapter(ad);
  } else {
    ad.notifydatasetchanged();
  }
}
```

Then in the postExecute you need to call this setListAdapter method....

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 //your code
 try{
   //your code
   setListAdapter()
 }catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();//use log i.e Log.e(TAG,msg)}  
}
```

2) Use a `ProgressBar view` in you application to inform user about loading is in progress. You can make it visible and start in PreExecute And stop and visibility gone in PostExecute

Comment: Already did this approach now i am getting gibberish data but not the actual data

Comment: I have added modified code based on the observation in your code added in question bcoz I feel adapter is not properly implemented...just try it then print the actual data on logcat and compare it with the view....

Comment: after making these changes also i am not getting any data from adapter. Even in logcat i am not getting data